# Cloned item throwing Layout Not Found

Tags: upgrade, item-clones

Working on an upgraded solution from Sitecore 7.2 (rev. 141226) to Sitecore 8.1 Update 2 (160302).

Recently an issue was reported that Cloned Items stopped working after the upgrade. Clone any Item and publish to Web database, while browsing the URL for that item, we get `Layout Not Found`.

We already verified that item exist in web database. By digging more deeper observed that if we `Transfer` the item to Web Database, it works fine but if we `Publish` we get the error.

Did any one encounter such problem earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is caused by a bug 108405, which was fixed in Sitecore 8.1 update 3.

108405: Final Layout is empty after publishing a clone.
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Update3/Release%20Notes

We raised a Support ticket for the same. Try this [Hot Fix](https://dl.sitecore.net/hotfix/Sitecore%20CMS%208.1%20rev.%20160302%20Hotfix%20108405-1.zip) provided by Sitecore.

Please be aware that the hotfix was built specifically for 8.1 Update 2 (rev 160302).